dimension of $S^2 \times S^1$
I just started thinking about 3-manifolds.
I know that the definition of a 3-manifold is essentially: a 2nd-countable Hausdorff topological space that locally looks like a 3-dimensional Euclidean space.
And I came to wonder, if it is straightforward to justify whether or not some common examples that appear are 3-manifolds.
For instance, $S^2 \times S^1 $ is a 3-manifold - why?.
My idea for the reasoning is as following: $S^2\times S^1$ is "nice" (no need to worry about differentiability, coordinate neighborhoods, etc., these properties coming from $S^1$ and $S^2$) and since $S^2\times S^1$ cannot be embedded in $\mathbb R^3$ but can be embedded in $\mathbb R^4$, we conclude that it is a 3-manifold...?
Thanks a lot.

The definition lacks rigor and that’s probably why it doesn’t seem natural to you. If one takes a local chart $\phi$ around one point $p \in S^2$ and another local chart $\psi$ around another point $q \in S^1$, then their product $\phi \times \psi$ provides a local chart for the point $(p,q) \in S^2 \times S^1$.

The Klein bottle is a 2-dimensional manifold which cannot be embedded in $\Bbb R^3$ but can be embedded in $\Bbb R^4$. THis shows that your heuristic is not valid.

It's fairly straightforward to prove that the (Cartesian) product of two manifolds is a manifold in all the common categories (topological, PL, smooth, complex, symplectic, etc). In each case (since we can prove it for the topological case to which all the rest reduce), the product of an $n$-manifold and an $m$-manifold is an $(n+m)$-manifold.

@BrevanEllefsen (being picky) in all the category but that of manifolds with boundary

@Didier specifically in the category of smooth manifolds with boundary, yes; Cartesian products aren't closed. (And one is forced to either concede the smooth structure or work with smooth manifolds with corners)

take a lite hike: https://juanmarqz.wordpress.com/cucei-maths/elementary-3-manifolds/

This has nothing to do with whether or not $S^2 \times S^1$ can be embedded in this or in that.
It has to do, instead, with what it means for something to "look, locally, like an $n$-dimensional Euclidean space". I'll put some rigor on that in a moment, but first let me work through this example.
First step: we need the fact that $S^2$ is a $2$-manifold: it looks, locally, like a $2$-dimensional Euclidean space.
Second step: we need that $S^1$ is a $1$-manifold: it looks, locally, like a $1$-dimensional Euclidean space.
Third step: combining the previous two steps, it follows that the product $S^2 \times S^1$ looks, locally, like the product of a 2-dimensional Euclidean space and a $1$-dimensional Euclidean space --- which is the same as a $3$-dimensional Euclidean space. Therefore $S^2 \times S^1$ is a $3$-manifold.
This same argument shows that the product of any $2$-manifold with any $1$-manifold is a $2+1=3$ manifold, and more generally that the product of an $m$-manifold with an $n$-manifold is an $m+n$-manifold.

So, what does all this "looks locally" stuff mean?

Definition: To say that a topological space $M$ is an $n$-manifold means that $M$ is a second countable Hausdorff space, and for every $p \in M$ there exists an open subset $U \subset M$ such that $p \in U$ and $U$ is homeomorphic to $(-1,1)^n \subset \mathbb R^n$.

And with that definition, you can easily walk through the three steps and formalize them. The one extra formality that you need to fill in is very simple: $(-1,1)^m \times (-1,1)^n$ is homeomorphic to $(-1,1)^{m+n}$.

You may need the following proposition.
Proposition. Suppose $\{ M_i \}_{1 \le i \le k}$ are smooth manifolds without boundary, and $ \dim M_i = n_i $, then

$ M :=M_1 \times \cdots \times M_k $ is a topological manifold;
there exists a smooth structure over $ M $ such that all the natural projective maps, i.e. $ \pi_i : M \to M_i $ are smooth.

This smooth structure makes $ M $ into a smooth manifold without boundary of dimension $ n_1 + \cdots + n_k $, called the product smooth manifold structure.
The proof is easy, and I believe that it can be found in any textbook on smooth manifolds. For example, you may find it in John M. Lee' s book Introduction to Smooth Manifold, see Example1.8 and Example 1.34.
